# NGINX 404 for sub folders on wordpress

Tags: wordpress, nginx

So I have an nginx server and i have a bunch of **wordpress websites** on them like so

```
/var/www/html/siteone
/var/www/html/sitetwo
```

When i use my browser to go to http://localserver/siteone, it works, but when i go to a sub folder or sub page, for example http://localserver/siteone/about it will always 404.

I know you're supposed to set up multiple location blocks however I dont want to do this! I want to be able to add a folder to the root, drop in the wordpress files and everything work. Any suggestions?

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

        root /var/www/html;

        index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name _;


        location / {

                #try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
                index index.php index.html index.htm;


                #try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;

                fancyindex on;
                fancyindex_localtime on;
                fancyindex_exact_size off;
                fancyindex_header "/Nginx-Fancyindex-Theme-light/header.html";
                fancyindex_footer "/Nginx-Fancyindex-Theme-light/footer.html";
                fancyindex_ignore "Nginx-Fancyindex-Theme-light";
                fancyindex_ignore "phpmyadmin";

        }

        location ~ \.php$ {

                client_max_body_size 1024M;

                include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
                # With php-fpm (or other unix sockets):
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_intercept_errors on;

                # With php-cgi (or other tcp sockets):
                #fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        }


        location ~ /\.ht {
                deny all;
        }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you've set permalinks properly inside wordpress admin area under reading? Might be as simple as resetting that and saving changes.